# Check if bot has been pinged

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've got a bot and if it gets pinged in a message I want it to "die." I found an answer on here and tried it and it does not work. I was wondering if there has been a change.

```
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if(message.mentions.has(but.user)) {
        message.reply("The bot will now die. Have a nice day!")
        client.destroy();
    }
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the client's id to check the mention Collection

```js
if (message.mentions.users.has(client.user.id)) {

}
```